# how to replace part of string with something else?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

```
var string='url("images/bgtr.svg") top right no-repeat, url("images/bgbl.svg") bottom left no-repeat, url("images/overlay.png"), linear-gradient(45deg, #5f796b, #3a4e59, #2f394e);'
```

how to replace `linear-gradient(45deg, #5f796b, #3a4e59, #2f394e)` with different characters? it might not always be 'linear gradient'

Comment: What do you mean by different string?

Comment: `string.replace("linear-gradient(45deg, #5f796b, #3a4e59, #2f394e","something else");`  I can see you tried really hard before asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Are there any known set of strings that can be in place of `linear-gradient` in the `var string`?

Comment: @RahulDesai anything seen in `var string` between commas, and most likely something else

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String.prototype.replace()` - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

> The `replace()` method returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement. The pattern can be a string or a RegExp, and the replacement can be a string or a function to be called for each match.

I have assumed `test` as the *different string* in the code snippet below.

```js
var string='url("images/bgtr.svg") top right no-repeat, url("images/bgbl.svg") bottom left no-repeat, url("images/overlay.png"), linear-gradient(45deg, #5f796b, #3a4e59, #2f394e);'

var replacedString = string.replace('linear-gradient(45deg, #5f796b, #3a4e59, #2f394e)', 'test');

console.log(replacedString);
```

Comment: Not enough regex! *it might not always be 'linear gradient'*

Comment: @revo Thats what the OP has in the question. How do you know it may not always be 'linear gradient'?

Comment: If it might not be *linear-gradient* all the time, then it means it's not a static  string therefore `replace` method shouldn't receive first argument as a static pattern.

Comment: String.replace can take regex so something lije: `String.replace('[-\w]*\(\d+deg, #[a-z0-9]+, #[a-z0-9]+, #[a-z0-9]+\) ', 'blah')`

Comment: Although... Not entirely sure what u are doing but if your trying to read a webpage/html doc u should prob use an HTML parser instead of regex ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @RSHAP I'm trying to replace one of the html values between commas with javascript. so no external parser. linear-gradient is the problematic value